# unauthorized(401) error in jquery laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

i developed the API in Laravel for authentication and authorization. while user user authentication at api side (through postman) is working fine, as i login from the API from front side it giving unauthorized error

[image]

below is my code where i am getting it wrong. or am I using wrong approach at frontend side?

```
   $(function () {
            $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: {
                            'X-XSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
                    }
            });
    });
    
  $('#ajaxcall').on('click', function(e) {
      
       
          e.preventDefault();
                var email = $('#email').val();
                var password = $('#password').val();
                var token = $('input[name="_token"').val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '{{url("api/login")}}',
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                        '_token': token,
                        'email': email,
                        'password': password
                    },
                    success: function(res) {
                        console.log(res)
                        if (res.error) {
                            $('#loginerror').text(res.error)
                        }
                        if (res.success) {
                            window.location.href = '/home';
                        }
                    }
                })
          
   });
```

laravel code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
//use Illuminate\Http\Request;
//use Illuminate\Http\Requests\LoginRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\LoginRequest;
use App\Http\Helpers\Helpers;
use App\Http\Resources\UserResource;
use Auth;
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function login(LoginRequest $request)
    {
    
        if(!Auth::attempt($request->only('email','password')))
        {
            Helpers::sendError('Email or password is wrong !!!');
        }
        return new UserResource(auth()->user());
    }
// }
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\validator;
use App\Http\Helpers\Helpers;


class LoginRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     */
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule|array|string>
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {
                

        /*return [
            //
        ];*/
        return['email'=>'required|email|exists:users,email','password'=>'required'];
        
    }
    public function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
        
        Helpers::sendError('validation error',$validator->errors());
    }
}
```

Comment: If it works through Postman, then your request from your front end must be different.  Try to compare the outgoing request from your browser's "Network" tab with the request you are issuing via Postman and see what is different.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this in your root file(blade) layout and also make sure your **login route is not wrapped with middleware** because that can make the 401 error occur too.

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

and then in your javascript, you can do this

```
      let _token   = $.('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
  $('#ajaxcall').on('click', function(e) {
      
       
          e.preventDefault();
                var email = $('#email').val();
                var password = $('#password').val();
                var token = _token ;
                $.ajax({
                    url: '{{url("api/login")}}',
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                        '_token': token,
                        'email': email,
                        'password': password
                    },
                    success: function(res) {
                        console.log(res)
                        if (res.error) {
                            $('#loginerror').text(res.error)
                        }
                        if (res.success) {
                            window.location.href = '/home';
                        }
                    }
                })
          
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

you should also add this in main layout blade file

```
<head>
    <meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
  </head>
```

Comment: Already added but not get any output